# Object reference not set to an instance of an object c#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, listbox

I have a listbox and i'm trying to select an item to display a label. My code is as follows:

```
private void listBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;

        var selected = lb.SelectedValue.ToString();
        //string selected = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

        label5.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        if (selected.ToString() == "Study Date")
        {
            label5.Content = "Format:YYYYMMDD";

        }

        if (selected.ToString() == "Patient's Name") label5.Content = "Enter name in string format.";
     }
```

But when i click on an item, i get an error as: `Object reference not set to instance of an object`. I cannot enter the code in the Selection changed event, so please tell me how I can go about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a potential issue here:

```
var selected = lb.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

You are calling `ToString()` even though SelectedValue can be `null`

Before you call `ToString()` make sure `SelectedValue` is not `null`

Comment: Hi @icarus, i removed the ToSrting part, my lb.SelectedValue is null, even though i am clicking on an item. :( Thanks!

Comment: @user877852: See? that was the issue! mouse_down is not the method you should be handling. At that point nothing has been selected yet. You probably need to handle OnSelectedIndexChanged or something similar. I am not a WPF developer so I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Yeah i figured that its empty. Okay no problem, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the `MouseDown()` event fires before the selection is registered. Wouldn't you be better off using the `SelectionChanged()` event?

Comment: Hi, i dont seem to have an event like that :(

Comment: I've always coded it like this `<ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"...>`

Comment: Hi, i put it in the selection changed event, and its working now! o.O thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could assist.